# filter using join model ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I need to show posts from users who have an active subscription.

**model/user.rb**

```
has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
```

**model/profile.rb ->suscription**

```
belongs_to :user, dependent: :destroy
scope :active, -> (as_of_date = Date.current) { where('? BETWEEN start_suscription AND end_suscription', as_of_date) } // return true is active
```

**model/post.rb**

```
belongs_to :user, dependent: :destroy
```

how do I do the query?

Comment: Can you check this query in your console? Post.joins(user: :profile).where('? BETWEEN start_suscription AND end_suscription', Date.current). I don't have a way to check this query.

Comment: @Mohanraj it works, thanks

Comment: Thanks, let me add in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Post.joins(user: :profile).merge(Profile.active)
```

This will generate the same query as in the `@mohanraj`'s answer. But when using this solution you don't have to repeat existing code (DRY Principle).

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below model query,

```
Post.joins(user: :profile).where('? BETWEEN start_suscription AND end_suscription', Date.current)
```